# Designing AC kick solenoid lock

Tags: ac, coil, solenoid, electromagnetic

I am making a kick solenoid lock with AC.

I designed the circuit to run on 220 V, 50 Hz (household plug.)

The inductor (coil) is air core
500 turns, 150 meter (500 ft) in length with inductive reactance of 55 Ω.

DC resistance of the coil is 8.6 Ω

According to Ohm's law, the current should be 4 A so the solenoid will be 880 watt.

This the circuit.

[image]

I have some questions:

1. Is the design OK? Will the circuit draw 4 A?
2. Will there be a loss in current or power? If so how to find it (calculation)?
3. Will 880 W, 220 V and 4 A create a strong electromagnetic field to be used as a kick solenoid?

Comment: Dc resistance should also be known ... and some ... about wire used.

Comment: Why dc resistance should be know?, 18awg

Comment: Because current drawn will depend on the complex impedance and power dissipated will depend on resistance.

Comment: 8.6 ohm dc resistance

Comment: Magnetic field can be calculated by simple formulae: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid

Current will be limited (roughly) by AC and DC resistance in series. Magnetic field, and thus, force will be sinusoidal. Required force depends on what you want to kick.

Comment: @Transistor It is pure inductor no any other resistance or component

Comment: "*It is pure inductor ...*" There's no such thing in the real world. A pure inductor would have zero resistance. Yours has 8.6 ohms.

Comment: EE&O, current is ~ 4 A, real power dissipated is ~125 **W**, and reactive power is ~ 860 **VA** (not W) for a total of ~ 880 **VA** ... Heating a "lot" ... so, "temperature" would be calculated.

Comment: How you calculated this? This solenoid will work by push button just for 1s or less

Comment: These are "steady" conditions giving an idea of "magnitude". If the button is pushed 1s (which was not defined) then the calculus is a "transient" analysis depending on all the variables in the system and the "time starting" (random) in the sinusoidal wave  ... Does the inductance remains "constant" in a "kick" solenoid? ...

Comment: Yes inductance is constant, according to your words, the current, voltage will depends on sinusoidal wave, so if i push button when the voltage wave is nealy zero will cause the current decrease so much too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simulation where you can see what happens when you push a button in a "inductive" circuit. Equations can also be written ...

[image]

There is 3 phases in the behavior.

1- When you just push the "button" (here, it is a "clean" push ...).
The starting current (~ 9 A peak) can be somewhat higher then in steady state because of the switching transient. It is a function relative to the voltage "phase" at starting "push".

2- Steady state (current calculated as usual in "sinusoidal" circuits).

3- When button is released, energy in inductor (if not equal to zero) will try "continue" the current, but it can't. As there is always a parasitic capacitor in parallel, energy is released (\$1/2*L*I^2\$) and create an "impressive" impulse voltage (\$1/2*L*I^2 = 1/2*C*Umax^2\$ >> \$ Umax = sqrt(L/C)*I \$ ) that can disrupt "air", it is an "arcing" that we can see.
Here (Umax is only some kV). Voltage is reduced because of the "big" capacitor that was added .

Examples :
if I=5 ; L= 170 mH ; C = 0.1 uF ; then Umax =  6.5 kV.
if I=5 ; L= 170 mH ; C = 1.0 nF ; then Umax = 65.0 kV.

EDIT:
To prevent "high voltages" transient, use a [VDR](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29081/vdrs.pdf) (MOV).

[image]

See [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29079/varintro.pdf) for a correct choice of VDR

How to choose chart in the just above note ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this great analysis, so after push the button the current will be about 9A for some milliseconds?, the third phase did not understant what is (Vps) refer to and can voltage up to kilo voltage in this circuit?

Comment: Not always 9A. Function of the "phase" voltage input when button is pressed. It can be also - 9 A or anything else (perhaps 0 sometimes). Third phase (when button just released)  is a "transfer" of "magnetic" energy of inductor (if any, because current is not equal to zero at that time) to electrostatic energy. Vps is the voltage across inductor at any time. When button pressed, Vps=220*sqrt(2) sine Voltage.

Comment: Do i need to use snubber in this circuit?

Comment: As it is used with AC, something as a VDR is needed. Added in answer.

Comment: The problem with vdr, it work for once one protection the will be needed to replace and with every push to button will very high voltage (kv) ( current not equal zero) as per your analysis need to be discharge

Comment: Ok.  Did not know that it was for once work only). Snubber as I used (R-C-) added also ... If I remember well, also TRANSIL diode+serial Resistor could do the some job ?

Comment: You should read this https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-types/varistor/# and this https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/varistor.html#:~:text=Varistor%20Summary,generated%20by%20inductive%20switching%20transients. If VDR chosen carefully,  it can be used because, here, transient is "short" (disrupt energy to be calculated)  and solenoid does not function very often. Technical note : https://www.manualshelf.com/manual/vishay/vdrs07h275bse/1-brochure-english/page-12.html

Comment: https://www.vishay.com/search/?searchChoice=part&query=technical%20note%20vdr%20resistor https://www.vishay.com/docs/29079/varintro.pdf How to use/choose these VDR.